# Incorrect result of InverseFourierTransform

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

When executing in 13.2 on Windows 10, the command

```
FourierTransform[DiracDelta@Cos[x], x, s]
```

results in
`Sum[Sqrt[2/Pi]*Cos[(Pi*K[1])/2]* DiracDelta[s + K[1]], {K[1], -Infinity, Infinity}]`.
Then

```
InverseFourierTransform[%, s, x]
```

> `Sum[(E^(I*x*K[1])*Cos[(Pi*K[1])/2])/Pi, {K[1], -Infinity, Infinity}]`

, but this series diverges since

```
DiscreteLimit[(E^(I*x*K[1])*Cos[(Pi*K[1])/2])/Pi, K[1] -> Infinity, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]
```

produces `Indeterminate`,
i.e. a necessary condition for the convergence of a series does not hold. In fact,`DiracDelta@Cos[x]` is nothing but scaled and shifted
`DiracComb` in WL notation. However, [the current explanation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffmgrmcczr1p7tl/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202023-02-22%2010.56.52.png?dl=0) of its Fourier transfom in the last column of 316
in [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#External_links) does not give any reference to  "the fact that
$$\sum _{n=-\infty }^{\infty }e^{inx}= 2\pi\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty }\delta (x+2\pi k)$$
as distributions".

Is there a workaround?

Comment: This is [CASE:5007060] recently submitted by me.

Comment: I guess the result could be considered as a formalism for a Dirac comb. But as a sum, certainly it diverges. A DiracComb, suitably scaled, would be a more appropriate result.